# MySQL display all date in between range

Tags: mysql, date, range

I want to display all dates between a `from` and `to` dates from MySQL.

For example the data from `schedule` table that has `from` and `to` fields are:

`from` date is `2013-3-13`,  and

`to` date is `2013-3-20`,

my desired result is:

```
 2013-3-13
 2013-3-14
 2013-3-15
 2013-3-16
 2013-3-17
 2013-3-18
 2013-3-19
 2013-3-20
```

How can I achieve this using MySQL query only (without having to use stored procedure 'cause I'm not familiar with it)?

**EDIT:**

[The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range) is very helpful, though I still don't fully get what is desired. In [this sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/5946), it only runs successfully but doesn't output anything. And I don't know what seems to be the problem.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: are this dates present on the database or you want to fill the gaps between dates?

Comment: Only dates from and to are present. The dates in between are not, so I want to fill the gaps.

Comment: ok, here is a great article to fill up dates [Using MySQL to generate daily sales reports with filled gaps](http://www.richnetapps.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/) basically create a calendar.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do it? I mean without adding MySQL procedure?

Comment: @bluefeet, the accepted answer there is great. However, when I changed the dates to `2013-3-1` and `2013-3-13`, The output ranges only from `2013-3-1` up to `2013-3-5`.

Comment: @xjshiya That's because that query goes back from the current date, and you ran it on 2013-3-5. Change it to go back from the end date that you want instead. E.g., see [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/5972).

Comment: @RedFilter, what if I want to exclued a certain date to the result of that query you provided? How can I restrain the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following to generate your list of dates:

```
select a.Date,  s.*
from 
(
  select curdate() + INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
  from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
  cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
  cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a
inner join schedule s
  on a.Date >= s.fromDate 
  and a.Date <= s.toDate
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cbc0/13)

Comment: how can I union another query with this code? `SELECT acode FROM reservation`? Thanks.

Comment: @xjshiya Please post a new question with the details on the new problem.  It will be easier than going back and forth in the comments. :)

Answer (score -4):

try where from date is 2013-3-13, and to date is 2013-3-20,

```
"SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE Field BETWEEN $fromdate AND $todate";
```

Comment: **-1** He don't want to printe all rows between two dates, instead he wants to print all `dates` between given two dates.