# MySQL autogenerate all possible combinations as rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables Channels, DateSelection and History. Channels and DateSelection are updated as needed and are typically like below
**Channels** Table -

```
  CHID    CHNAME    CHLOC                     

  1        BARRY     NULL                           

  2        TOM       NULL

  3        SHIRLY    NULL
```

**DateSelection** Table

```
WEEKCOMMENCING       WEEKENDING

  01/01/2014        03/01/2014
```

**History** Is Empty with columns -               Channel - Date  - User

What i would like to do is run a query or trigger mysql or php etc that would make rows of

```
Channel   -    Date    -     User

  Barry         01/01/2014

  Barry         02/01/2014

  Barry         03/01/2014

  Tom           01/01/2014

  Tom           02/01/2014

  Tom           03/01/2014

 Shirly         01/01/2014

 Shirly         02/01/2014

 Shirly         03/01/2014
```

Essentially every possible combination?

I have got it sort of working with the following in a view. and doing each day independently

INSERT INTO FCHISTORY

(CHNAME, DATE)

SELECT Channels.CHNAME, FCCURRENTDATES.DATE

FROM Channels

CROSS JOIN FCCURRENTDATES

However this creates duplicates constantly. What can I add to only have 1 of each matching combination of CHNAME and DATE

Can someone help me out here? I dont mind doing it in a one day at a time way but there is actually a cpl hundred channels. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that there will be an output row for reach month that is between weekcommencing and weekending?

Comment: an output row that saves to the HISTORY table for each day that is within the weekcommencing and ending. Australian we go DD/MM/YYYY :)

Comment: lol, that makes more sense! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223032/mysql-display-all-date-in-between-range

Comment: or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range - once you have this you can do a JOIN on the tables

Comment: read both of them in search earlier, thanks though. I also need to have the Channel field filled out so that for every channel there is every date

Comment: for the latter, just JOIN your table to the dates

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT CHNAME AS Channel, a.Date, '' AS User
FROM Channels c
JOIN DateSelection ds
JOIN (
  select curdate() + INTERVAL 100 DAY - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
  from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
  cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
  cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a ON a.Date BETWEEN ds.WEEKCOMMENCING AND ds.WEEKENDING
ORDER BY CHID, a.Date
```

See sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87a5f/19

Note that you might adjust the date range for selection depending on whether you are looking into the future or past. Right now the range is 900 days before the curdate and 100 days after. Adjust as needed.

Comment: cant get that working, where is the history table defined to write into?

Comment: does the query work on your end to produce output? for history, prepend 'INSERT INTO History'